# Complex Rails associations question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have three models of concern here:

- User
- Fight
- FightPunches
- Punches

The associations are as follows:

- User has many fights, foreign_key => 'challenger_id or challengee_id'
- Fight belongs to challenger, as User
- Fight belongs to challengee, as User
- Fight has many fight_punches
- FightPunches belongs to fight
- Fight has many punches, through fight_punches
- FightPunch belongs to Punch
- FightPunch belongs to User

Key notes:

- There are three fk's in the FightPunch model: fight_id, punch_id, user_id
- challenger_id and challengee_id reflect the two users who are fighting in the Fight model.

Here is the challenge.  I want to create two associations in the Fight model:

1. has_many challenger_punches
2. has_many challengee_punches

The first must grab the records from the Punch model; however, it must only grab those records where Fight.challenger_id = FightPunch.user_id.

Same with #2, but just dealing with the challengee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[belongs_to documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to) look under supported options, specifically "foreign_key" and "primary_key"